# Make MAP return other than single cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With MAP I can easily return single cell values, like in

```
 =MAP(SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(x,x*x))
```

However, if I try to return compound values (ranges or arrays) it doesn't seem to work, like in

```
 =MAP(SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(x,HSTACK(x,x*x)))
```

... and I get a CALC! error.

Is there any workaround that allows me to return ranges/arrays with the MAP function?

Comment: On a lighter note, without using `MAP()` or `LAMBDA()` --> `=SEQUENCE(5)^{1,2}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lambda functionality I suppose you could try `REDUCE()` instead of `MAP()` which would allow internal stacking during iteration:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,IF({1,0},b,b*b)))),1)
```

Or:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(b,b*b)))),1)
```

With the benefit of the 2nd option that you can add n amount of calculations.

---

Though if you want to avoid `LAMBDA()` helpers, this can easily be achieved through the use of `LET()`:

```
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(5),HSTACK(a,a*a))
```

Comment: Your answer is excellent, JvdV, just what I needed

Answer (score 3):

If you actually wanted to use Map, I suppose something like this:

```
=--LET(lmda,MAP(SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(x,x&"|"&x*x)),HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(lmda,"|"),TEXTAFTER(lmda,"|")))
```

[image]

Comment: Edited in a double unary to return numbers if you don't mind. Btw, this to me does not feel like `MAP()` nomore but rather a nice intellectual challenge =)

Comment: Your are right, Tom. In general, I find it difficult for a dynamic array function to return a compound value (i.e. a pair of values). The question was asked with the MAP function, but I could've asked it also with, say, REDUCE

Comment: Yes, although it does answer your question if taken literally, I can see that you were hoping for a more general answer as proposed by @JvdV. In particular, I can't see how mine could be expanded to more than two columns because textsplit doesn't work with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I know am *quite late* here, but this can be solved without using `MAP()` or without using `LAMBDA()`, however as **OP** insisted about using with `MAP()` then above answers have already made the point to resolve, perhaps here is what I *tried*.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A1`

```
=SEQUENCE(5)^{1,2}
```