# Divide a value in excel by a set of preset values to find out how many of each are needed

Tags: excel

I am curious if there is a way to make my life easier. In excel I am producing a total value, say 750 and need to find out how many orders of pipe I need from values of 50,100,200,250,500. Is there anyway to have excel take a value and then return how many of each of these numbers I would need, so for the 750 case 1 500 and 1 250?

Currently the solution is just worked out in my head

Comment: Why not `375+375`

Comment: it has to be from the list [50 100 200 250 500] they're the products we provide

Comment: Will a solution always be possible with no remainder/excess? Where multiple solutions are possible, what determines which should be preferred?

Comment: So if its say 823, it will over shoot the value (500+250+100) and where multiple solutions are possible it will choose to maximise highest values, so as many 500s then 250s etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to try to fit pipes in decreasing order of size,and that you have access to the required functions, you can use Reduce as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348035/make-map-return-other-than-single-cell-values/74348783?noredirect=1#comment131262069_74348783) to step through the sizes and successively divide by each one although the formula is a little laboured:

```
=LET(pipes,{500;250;200;100;50},reqd,750,DROP(REDUCE(0,pipes,
LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,QUOTIENT(reqd-IF(ROWS(a)>1,SUM(DROP(a,1)*TAKE(pipes,ROWS(a)-1)),0),c)))),1))
```

[image]

As pointed out by @Jos Woolley, this may not give you the answer you want if the total is something like 749. It will fit as many values in as possible and give a result 500+200 total 700 (remainder 49). You could fix it perhaps by rounding up to the next multiple of 50.

For the example of 823, you would have:

```
=LET(pipes,{500;250;200;100;50},reqd,CEILING(823,MIN(pipes)),DROP(REDUCE(0,pipes,
LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,QUOTIENT(reqd-IF(ROWS(a)>1,SUM(DROP(a,1)*TAKE(pipes,ROWS(a)-1)),0),c)))),1))
```

[image]

which gives 500+250+100=850.

---

Well I've got a bit obsessed with this now and I am determined to get a lambda working to find the optimal answer! I have been looking at the brute-force solution to finding the minimum *number* of coins required to make up a given total in the reference mentioned previously and have managed to translate it into a lambda using Reduce:

```
 Mincoins1= LAMBDA(coins, m, v,
    IF(
        v <= 0,
        0,
        REDUCE(
            999,
            coins,
            LAMBDA(a, c,
                IF(v >= c, LET(mc, mincoins1.mincoins1(coins, m, v - c) + 1, IF(mc < a, mc, a)), a)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This does give the correct answer, 2, for the case when you want to make up a value of 400 from the list of pipes given. The next step will be to modify the code to return the list of pipes which give that total (200,200).

https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/minimum-coin-change

Here is the lambda modified to return a string containing the chosen pipes:

```
 Mincoins2= LAMBDA(coins, m, v,
    IF(
        v <= 0,
        "",
        REDUCE(
            rept("x",999),
            coins,
            LAMBDA(a, c,
                IF(v >= c, LET(mc, c&"|"&mincoins2.mincoins2(coins, m, v - c), IF(len(mc) < len(a), mc, a)), a)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

[image]

It does work BUT (and this is a big but) it hits a limit as soon as the value to be produced exceeds 1000 and you get a #value error. Disappointing. But interesting I think as a proof of concept.

Comment: As indicated in my answer, 400 might give a problem (giving 250 + 100 + 50 while 200 + 200 contains less bills), how does your proposal cope with that?

Comment: You are right of course, it just follows an algorithm where it fits the largest size first which is relatively simple to do. My fairly crude fix of rounding up to the next multiple of 50 for inexact fit wouldn't always work either. But I haven't seen a better alternative so far...

Comment: Going into this a bit more deeply, it is equivalent to the problem of making change for a given amount of money with the smallest number of coins. This seems to be a fairly well-known problem and you can find pseudo-code for it here for example https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/minimum-coin-change  which offers recursive solutions. In principle it could be implemented with a lambda (this would be a fairly heroic piece of work) but in practice you would need VBA I think so as @Dominique says it is by no means an easy problem to solve optimally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but lets try.

if you have 1 450 to divide, have a formula that divides 1 450 with you highest lenght (750) and then round it down.

so the formula would be something of the line: = rounddown(1 450 / 750; 0)

you will then get the answer that you need 1 of the length 750.

then keep the info about how much length you have remaining. So a formula like:
=1 450 - 750 * [the answer from previous formula = 1]. this would sum to 700.

then start over with the same thing, but divide 700 with 500 (second largest size).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely difficult: one might think for this easy solution, starting with `value_begin`:

```
amount_of_500 = value_begin DIV 500; // integer division
temp = value_begin - 500 * amount_of_500;
amount_of_250 = temp DIV 250; // again integer division
temp = temp - 250 * amount_of_250;
amount_of_200 = temp DIV 200; // again integer division
temp = temp - 200 * amount_of_200;
...
```

However, this will not work because of the value 200, which is far too close to 250: just start with `value_begin` equal to 400 (algorithm solution : 250 + 100 + 50, while best solution : 200 + 200).

Are you sure you need both 200 and 250 as possible numbers to divide by? If yes, you might have a serious problem getting this implemented.

Comment: sadly yes as it is a product we sell, if it is too complicated do not worry it is simple enough to calculate by hand/in your head I was just curious if an easy solution existed

Comment: @JamesMetcalfe: The algorithm I've shown is indeed an easy solution, but as I mentioned: there's a catch: you will get a correct result, but the total amount of bills will not be minimal, as shown with the "400" example. As a result, 200 bills won't be used that often. If you're ok with this, you can actually implement this algorithm.