# Find the number of items it takes to reach 85% in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I am looking to find a way in excel to take a column of percentages and find the number of entries it would take to get to `85%`. The function needs to find the largest values from the population, sum and count the number of entries it would take to reach 85%.

For example given the following percentages:

```
10%, 12% 2%, 10% 20%, 5%, 20% 30%, 5% 12%, 15%
```

Sum together: `30%, 20%, 20%, 15%` to reach `85%` and return the value `4`.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359156/divide-a-value-in-excel-by-a-set-of-preset-values-to-find-out-how-many-of-each-a It's fairly easy to take the largest first, but this doesn't always lead to the best solution.

Comment: This is so called "Subset sum problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem you might want to start looking for 
 solution combining it with Excel keyword

Comment: @tariq do you want to sum to exactly 85% or at least 85%?

Comment: at least 85%. The value can be more for odd percentages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that B2:B12 contains the data.

For O365 versions...

```
=MATCH(TRUE,SCAN(0,SORT(B2:B12,,-1),LAMBDA(i,a,i+a))>=0.85,0)
```

For older versions, try the following formula that needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(IF(ROW(B2:B12)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B12)),1,0),LARGE(B2:B12,ROW(B2:B12)-ROW(B2)+1))>=0.85,0)
```